# block download canceled, geth 1.5.9 would not download blocks

Tags: blockchain, synchronization

when starting out geth I cant download past block 1292880

[image]

does anyone have any idea why it would not download any more blocks?

Comment: Hi there. A couple of things to check. Firstly, check you have some peers by running `admin.peers` from Geth's console (by `attach`ing if necessary). Next, you could try restarting Geth with a higher logging verbosity. Try `--verbosity 5` or `--verbosity 6`.

Comment: when I type in admin.peers it shows me not much connections... when I put in cmd geth --verbosity 6 it starts goin but doesnt seems like it downloads blocks because the count of the blocks remaining the same 1292880 after running it for quite some time.

Comment: most of my peers looking like that: with the difficulty and version marked in red 

caps: ["eth/63"],
    id: "07602a45f621149610043265c95644c7d1a663bd3c207c96ec51ef9be28b128f765fa27f1e08fa94cfcf78a29a37d46d52ffbfb2fd2730298f11eebfba92b4c2",
    name: "Geth/v1.5.9-stable-a07539fb/darwin/go1.7.4",
    network: {
      localAddress: "192.168.0.101:57345",
      remoteAddress: "24.229.203.72:30303"
    },
    protocols: {
      eth: {
        difficulty: 17179869184,
        head: "0xd4e56740f876aef8c010b86a40d5f56745a118d0906a34e69aec8c0db1cb8fa3",
        version: 63
      }

Comment: UPDATE: let the --verbosity 6 run and it showed me where the file was corrupted. Deleted the .ldb file from the blockchain and it seems to be working now. Thank you very much Richard Horrocks!